# Get a value from View to Controller dynamically

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am currently working on a ASP .NET web application. It will have a dynamic interface since the interface changes according to API responses (some of the dropdown menus include the responses from the RESTful API).

For instance I have a dropdown menu like this (right now it's static):

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">İl</span>
    <select id="il-select" style="height:inherit;">
        <option value="1">Category 1</option>
        <option value="2">Category 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And I want to get the option value of the selected category from View to Controller every time it changes, to use in another API request. I can get the selected option's value like this:

```
<script id="functions" type="text/javascript">
    $("#il-select").on('change', function () {
        var option_value = this.value;
        alert(option_value);
    });
</script>
```

However I don't know how to get every selected option's option value to the Controller dynamically to use.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What exactly you want you do on change of the selected value? What I assume you want is to make a request to a controller's method. What would be the response of this method and how are you going to use it?

Comment: When user selects an option, I need to get the option value so that I can use it in the HTTP request I'll send to the API. Every option value has its own property so for every option I'll get different responses from the API.

Comment: Ok, give me please an example of the url you would like to hit on option change and a response of this request.

Comment: For instance the options are some filters, and for every option value I get their filter types to use, and every option value represents a different filter type.

Comment: I cannot give an example URL right now. Let's assume my request is like: 
http://dev.blabla.com/username/testAPI/api.blabla.com/bla?optionvalue=x

And I get a JSON array as a response. For each option the user selects, I need to repeat this and get the result from API for that option.

Comment: I am sorry, but it is impossible to write a piece of code that could help you, since we don't know the case with details.

Comment: I'm just asking a little part of it. How can I pass a value from the View to Controller every time it changes.

Comment: Like every "on change" passing the value, or calling a function.

Comment: Is this helpfull http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/53624/22542 ? Use your browser translation, because I wrote in portuguese, but I think it's what you are looking for